# How to implement Object.create() in non ES5

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I've been reading numerous books and articles on Javascript recently and am stumped by the accepted version of Object.create in non ES5 environment. Douglas Crockford and Stoyan Stefanov have both mentioned a way of recreating Object.create functionality within non ES5 environments, and though their function names are different, you can see the implementation below:

```
function inherit(child, parent) {
    var f = function() {};
    f.prototype = parent.prototype;
    c.prototype = new f();
}
```

I understand that you wouldn't want to just copy the prototype directly, so the function acts as a proxy - preventing a change of the parent prototype causing problems with the child. What I don't understand is why the use of a new function? Isn't this the same:

```
function inherit(child, parent) {
    var o = {}:
    o.prototype = parent.prototype;
    c.prototype = o;
}
```

Could someone please clarify why they are different and why they've gone for the first version rather than mine (which appears to do the same thing?) - thanks in advance!

*Edit*

Here is some test code:

```
//inherit that uses a function as a proxy and creates a new instance as the child prototype
function inherit1(child, parent) {
    var f = function() {};
    f.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new f();
}

//inherit that stores prototype on an object and passes that to a prototype of the child
function inherit2(child, parent) {
    var o = {};
    o.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = o;
}

//Begin test for inherit1
function parent1() {}
parent1.prototype.talk = function() {console.log("from parent1 prototype");};

function child1() {}

inherit1(child1, parent1);

var kid1 = new child1();

kid1.talk(); //"from parent1 prototype"

//Begin test from inherit2
function parent2() {}
parent2.prototype.talk = function() {console.log("from parent2 prototype");}

function child2() {}

inherit2(child2, parent2);

var kid2 = new child2();

kid2.talk(); //kid2.talk() is not a function 
kid2.prototype.talk() //"from parent2 prototype"
```

//What happened here? For prototypical inheritance to work, does it have to inherit from a function?

Comment: So is it `c` or `child`?

Comment: You want to learn about `[[Prototype]]`, and how it is related to the `prototype` of a function.

Comment: Did you try to change the child in your approach and trying to observe if the parent is changed ?

Comment: elclanrs: does learning about [[Prototype]] look like it will explain the behaviour you can see in my edit (including test and results)?